# Предлагаю нам или вам?

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова, стиль

I'm translating this into Russian:

> Let us continue this discussion in chat.

and considering three options:

- This one seems more logical to me.

  > Предлагаю вам продолжить обсуждение в чате.
- This one emphasizes that I will also participate. But it sounds more like commercialese speech (канцелярит).

  > Предлагаю нам продолжить обсуждение в чате.
- Same friendliness, plus a clue about site mechanics, which allows copying all the comments into the newly created chat. What do you think of this one?

  > Давайте перенесём обсуждение в чат.

Are there other nuances? What should I use?

The context is StackExchange site interface, as you may have guessed already. Here's the original question: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1021/181472

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first version sounds more natural than the second one: it's better to avoid expressions literally offering something to yourself (нам -> 'both of you' includes yourself). However, it is possible to use "нам с вами" instead of "нам", then it would sound more like 'I suggest that you and I continue...' But a more exact translation is possible here (it also sounds slightly less formal):

```
Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
```

Comment: upvoted this, though personally for me "нам"-form sounds warmer, also, proposed better translation is indeed better and more likely form.

Comment: It is possible to say "нам с вами" in that version instead of "нам", then it would sound more like 'I suggest that you and me continue...'

Comment: very nice observation! If you add this to you question it will be even more valuable.

Comment: "Давайте" is definitely the most natural way of expressing this.

Comment: Thank you. There had been a similar option, but with an extra pronoun. I've added this one as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Предлагаю вам продолжить обсуждение в чате." Так может сказать модератор форума, заставляя юзеров покинуть форум и продолжить обсуждать оффтопик в чате.

"Предлагаю нам продолжить обсуждение в чате." - если собираетесь принять участие в этом обсуждении.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to difference between English "Let's move this discusssion to chat" (~"нам" form) and "I'd like to suggest you..." (~"вам" form). I'd rather disagree with @Alex_ander. To me "предлагаю нам" in this context sounds slightly more friendly and definitely less official than "предлагаю вам".

Though this is definitely very personal and I can imagine a lot of native speakers who will tend to agree with Alex_ander and equally - with me.

Comment: You could just offer me to include my answer into the question. I don't see why it's necessary to use heavy artillery here.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, it's not a heavy artillery, you haven't provided answer (to your own question)  you just added a  case you want to task about. If you don't agree with the fact of moderation itself, you can raise this question on meta. If you see a point in this changes, let's just move on.

Comment: it is as well an answer, as the Alex_ander's proposal: neither "нам", nor "вам", but a third option. Here I followed the rule that is accepted on meta.ru.so: each option should be a separate answer and not a part of the question. So it can be discussed and voted for. Tag wikis ([tag:перевод] & [tag:выбор-слова]) give no clue about how I should post such answers here, so how could I know that it's a wrong way?

Comment: But if you pointed me at this fact, I could explain my point and maybe fix the situation by myself. What's disappointing here is that you didn't let me do it. Most review operations add a predefined comment, so the author has time to react and improve their post.

Comment: From my opininon there was no room to discussion here. You've added a case for you own question as and answer, which ends with "What do you think of this one?" There was no chance it could end up anywhere rather than in question itself. Sorry, I've just didn't want to waste your time by encouraging you to make an edit which would be made anycase. Don't treat it like something negitve. In fact, I've upvoted you question.

Also, it is an iterative process. If you feel that your question can be improved  further you can edit it as well.